# Unit Testing seeing all Queues in the Org

Tags: apex, unit-test, queue

I need to fetch a List of all Queues in the org which allow Leads. To do this I created a function which does its job well. Now in Unit Testing, the problem I am facing is that the unit Tests see all the org data. That means all Queues that are already created in the org are also visible to my Uni test. I have checked that the seeallData flag is set to false, yet it shows all of them.

Please let me know if you have any information or if I may be missing something.

Answer (score 7):

That is standard behavior. Certain information is still available even if you are isolating your tests from the org's data.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_data_access.htm

Comment: But Queue isn't listed there. Documentation bug?

Comment: The documentation could be better but it actually says "such as:" so that would indicate they are not listing every single object but only a few examples.

Comment: Ah should have read it rather than searched it... thanks.